# Partial differential equation involving inverse

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

I am new to differential equations but I would like to study the following. I am looking for a function $\tilde{u}(x,y)$ with existing inverses $\tilde{x}(y,u)$ and $\tilde{y}(x,u)$. $k(x,y)$ is a known function that is twice continuously differentiable with $k_y>0$ and $k_x<0$. $D>0$ is a real number. I have $x \in [0,1]$ and $y \in [0, D]$, more specifically $\tilde{u}:  [0,1]\times [0, D] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}_+$. I am denoting with $\tilde{x}$ a function and with $x$ a variable.

$\tilde{u}(x,y)=k(x,y)-\frac{\tilde{x}(D-y,\tilde{u}(x,y))}{\tilde{x}_u(D-y,\tilde{u}(x,y))}$

How do I classify this equation and what can I say about existence of solutions?

Comment: You're getting your variables and functions muddled with your notation. I'd suggest making $f$ the function such that $f(y,u(x,y)) = x$. Then you can write $x(D-y,u)$ as $f(D-y, u(x,y))$ or $f(D-y,u(x,D-y))$ as appropriate.

Comment: I edited the question to make this more clear.

Comment: The complexity of this question does not really support your claim of being "new to differential equations" :D. Can you say a few words about the motivation behind the question? If you look at the above equation from the point of view of $x(u,y)$, it is just a non-linear differential equation with no inverses. Likely solvable for many different functions $k$, but there are certainly such $k$ for which it does not have a solution. Analytical solution likely does not exist for most non-trivial $k$. Finding all functions $k$ for which a solution exists may also be hard to impossible.

Comment: Thanks, you are right! I can get rid of the inverse with the change of variable $v=\tilde{u}(x,y)$ (and then $x=\tilde{x}(y,v)$). Then I got a differential equation with no inverses and both sides of the equality are functions of $y$ and $v$. How can I award the bounty to you? Maybe you need to make your comment an answer.